# Java best practice - Is declaring the constructor before the class variables a bad thing?

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm undertaking a 'static' code walkthrough of Java code from a colleague (another student)

To me, this doesn't make sense; reading from top to bottom these 'component' objects are instantiated (and later used in the constructor) before they are declared. But, the code happily compiles and runs. Is this bad practice?

```
Public Class theObject {

    private static final long aVariable = 123123123123123;

    public theObject(...){

        componentOne = new Component(...);
        componentTwo = new Component(...);

        ...
        ...
        componentOne.doSomething(...);
    }

    private Component componentOne;
    private Component componentTwo;
}
```

Comment: This is OOP!!!! ( kick .. fall in well). AFAIK There are certain style-cop checks which might highlight the fact that private members be declared before the constructor followed by declarations of public members but such declaration dont have any implications on the conpiler unlike in languages such as C

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Sun Microsystems (now taken over by Oracle) published its [Java Coding Style Guide](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.443.7443&rep=rep1&type=pdf) in 1998, in which they recommended a particular organization to class declarations:

1. Static variable field declarations
2. Instance variable field declarations
3. Static initializer
4. Static member inner class declarations [*]
5. Static method declarations
6. Instance initializer
7. Instance constructor declarations
8. Instance member inner class declarations [*]
9. Instance method declarations

Note that this puts the data declarations at the top of the file. (An [earlier Sun publication from 1997](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) did not cover everything in the above list.) The only important ordering is within the static fields and within the instance fields, and then only if the fields contain initializers that refer to other fields. You cannot use a field in an initializer before it itself has been initialized. Similarly, an initializer (item 3 or 6) cannot make a forward reference to a field, except as the target of an assignment. (See the [Java Language Specification, Section 8.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3), for more information on such forward references.) As far as I know, nothing else about the order matters.

[*] The terminology in the above list (which is verbatim from the 1998 guide) is out of date with regards to items 4 and 8. Specifically, from the [Java tutorial on nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> **Terminology:** Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared `static` are called *static nested classes*. Non-static nested classes are called *inner classes*.

In modern usage, there is no such thing as a "static member inner class".

Answer (score 10):

The general declaration order in java, (Reference: [Java Coding Style Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137946.html#182))

```
     public class DeclarationOrder {

        // Class (static) variables
        public static int publicClassVariable;
        protected static int protectedClassVariable;
        static int defaultClassVariable;
        private static int privateClassVariable;

        // Instance variables
        public int publicInstanceVariable;
        protected int protectedInstanceVariable;
        int defaultInstanceVariable;
        private int privateInstanceVariable;

        // Constructors
        public DeclarationOrder() {
            // Public Constructor
        }
        protected DeclarationOrder(int var) {
            // Protected Constructor
        }
        DeclarationOrder(String var) {
            // Default Constructor
        }
        private DeclarationOrder(Double var) {
            // private Constructor
        }

        // Class (static) Methods
        public static void publicClassMethod(){}
        protected static void protectedStaticMethod(){}
        static void defaultStaticMethod() {}
        private static void privateStaticMethod(){}

        // Instance Methods
        public void publicInstaceMethod() {}
        protected void protectedInstanceMethod() {}
        void defaultInstanceMethod() {}
        private void privateInstanceMethod() {}
    }
```

The order within each set should be,

1. Public
2. Protected
3. Package level (no access modifier)
4. Private

Answer (score 9):

There's no real consensus about this. Most people will declare class variables at the top of the class implementation followed by the methods but that's not a requirement. Some books like Code Complete suggest declaring variables as close as possible as their first use. This helps reducing the scope of a variable to a minimum.

Comment: @赢郭88888888, so the variable isn't "lost" in the code. If you declare every variable at the top of each file you might not know what is it used for when you review the code or simply work on it. The principle is: "I'm not going to use this variable before I declare this function so why would I declare it before now?". I personally don't really follow this rule but I know some people do and it is recommended in Code Complete.

Answer (score 5):

No they are not instantiated before thay are declared. The order of initialisation is fixed in Java and it doesn't matter *where* in the code you put your declarations and constructors.

As for convention, it really depends on what you are comfortable with. While the truth is the convention is to declare fileds first and then the constructors, your approach is as valid as any other, as long as it is not against your nature or company regulations.

Moreover, there is much more dangerous stuff to put in your code that makes it less readable, such as one-letter variables or extensive use of less common structures (ternary operator for complex conditions, for example). Organizing the code is one of the lesser concerns, as any decent IDE can reorganize the code by whatever settings you put there.

Answer (score 3):

The *order* in which the members of a class (methods, attributes) are declared is irrelevant. By convention it's common to first declare all attributes and constants, then the methods.

For example, in your code: it's possible to initialize the attributes in the constructor and *then* declare the attributes, simply because when a class is compiled all attribute declarations will be taken into account, and later, when the constructor is actually *called*, the attributes will be found. Notice that the attributes in the constructor are not being accessed at compile time, that's why they don't produce an error; they only get accessed at run time.

Comment: The order *can* matter `class X { int a = b + 1 ; int b = 100 }` is not the same as `class Y { int b = 100 ; int a = b + 1 ; }`  `class X` should not compile, but there is nothing wrong with `class Y`

Comment: As stated in my answer, the _declaration_ order of attributes doesn't matter. In your examples you're _initializing_ attributes, of course that's an entirely different story.

Answer (score 2):

It is contrary to normal conventions, and (as such) it makes the code less readable for people who expect the normal conventions to be followed ... i.e. most Java programmers.

On the other hand, if the code does this consistently, and it follows an agreed local coding convention, then readers will get used to it.

So the answer to the question *"Is this bad practice?"* is that it depends on your agreed coding convention, and what it says about this.

But the meta-answer is that doing a code review without an agreed coding convention is a really bad idea.  If there is no coding convention, there is no objective basis for reviewing code style.  You are liable to end up with a bad outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Main Java Language specification define in sections 8.1.1, 8.3.1 and 8.4.3 following flow which we have to using:

1. public
2. protected
3. private
4. abstract
5. static
6. final
7. transient
8. volatile
9. synchronized
10. native
11. strictfp

**This order we have to use when we are writing code in Java ;)**

[Link to the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html)